# how to fadeIn content with 2 sec delay in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, fadein

I am using this ajax script to for a form when submit. 
I am trying to fadIn the content ( php echo) with 2 sec. But the content appears immediately and is not fading in:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#subscribe_newsletter').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#subscribe_newsletter').val($(this).val());
        var data = $("#subscribe").serialize();

    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'newsletter/email_subscribe.php',
    data : data,
    success :  function(data)
           {                   
                $(".subscribe_wrapper").fadeIn(2000).show(function()
                {
                    $(".subscribe_wrapper").html(data);

                });

           }
    });

   });

});
```

The form:

```
<div id="form" class="subscribe_wrapper"></div>
        <form id="subscribe" method="POST">
                <input  name="email_subscribe" placeholder="Uw Email" type="text" />
                <input class="subscribe_newsletter nex-bc nex-cc nex-bgch" id="subscribe_newsletter" type="submit" name="submit" value="Inschrijven">
        </form>
```

Why does it not fadIn with 2 sec? Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: Are you returning output as json from php file ?

Comment: no the output is not returning as json

Comment: You could also use .animate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fadeIn(2000)` make the animation 2 Sec log.

Replace it to `.delay(2000).fadeIn(500)`

Answer (score 0):

Well your very close !

`.subscribe_wrapper` should be hidden as a start (by CSS or by jQuery).

Then you load the data and fade it in:

```
success :  function(data)
       {                

         $(".subscribe_wrapper").html(data);
         $(".subscribe_wrapper").fadeIn(2000, function()
                {
                 // Animation complete   
                });
```

Comment: Something is unclear : to what refers the extra closing `</div>` in your code?

Comment: oops...that was mistake. The last `</div>` is a mistake

Answer (score 0):

`.subscribe_wrapper` should be hidden as a start (by CSS or by jQuery).

Then you load the data and fade it in:

```
success: function(data){                
    $(".subscribe_wrapper").html(data);
    $(".subscribe_wrapper").delay(2000).fadeIn();
}
```